# Is there an opposite expression for 괜히?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, meaning

I feel like I learned a word that’s somewhat an opposite for 괜히 but I cannot remember what it was.

The specific situation is...

For 괜히... after being invited by a friend to a party and realizing it was boring... one can say 괜히 왔어..

But if it was the opposite.. where the friend didn’t want to go to the party expecting it would be boring and meaningless but after going, he/she enjoyed it more than expected. What expression can he/she say in this situation?

My teacher said 오길 잘했어 but I feel like there’s an actual word that can be used to express “I’m glad I came to the party (because it was actually more meaningful and fun than expected).” It might’ve been an adverb but I just can’t remember what it was.

Answer (score 4):

You can say "잘 왔어" for opposite for "괜히 왔어".
"잘" has very broad meaning, and is almost the same as "good".

for example of "잘",
잘했어 = Well done
나 이거 잘해 = I am good at this
나 이거 잘 못해 = I am not good at this

Answer (score 1):

1) When someone participates the party, then he can say :

잘못 왔네 (I have wrong level) : For instance, the party is only
  for women, or one blames him. That is, he can not find his goal

괜히 왔어 (I have no profit) : 괜히 adverb; without profit.

For instance, he can not find interesting things

오길 잘했어 (This party is desired one) : When he is satisfied. That is, this is actual expression for opposite of 괜히 왔어.

@ 잘 + verb : For instance, he study well (그는 공부 잘 한다)
 Here, 잘 is degree of verb. But here, 오길 잘 했어 = 오는 것을 잘
 선택했어 (To come here is a suitable decision). That is, 잘 means choice.

2) A : 여기 오느라 나 고생했어 (I spent a hard time to reach here)

B : 잘 왔어 (I am happy, because you come here)

3) A : 점심에 빵 먹었는데 맛있었어 (I ate a bread for lunch and it is tasty)

B : 잘했네 (You did a good job)